# change order of legends for multiple aesthetics

Tags: r, ggplot2

Another "legend - question".

I have several aesthetics and wish to specify the order in which the legends for each aesthetic are drawn. 
Most threads are about changing the order of the items *within* an aesthetic, but that's not my problem. In my example, I would like to specify the location of the fill legend. Funnily, the color legend is drawn on top of the fill legend, but "right" to the fill legend, when drawing the legend on the bottom. That seems somewhat random to left to right readers like me who also rather read from the top to the bottom.

The graph is obviously somewhat random and was just quickly made for reprex purpose.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(cyl, hp, fill = as.character(gear))) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(cyl, disp, color = as.character(cyl))) +
  labs(fill = 'fill', color = 'color')

# here I would like the fill legend to be *above* the color legend
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(cyl, hp, fill = as.character(gear))) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(cyl, disp, color = as.character(cyl))) +
  labs(fill = 'fill', color = 'color') +
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom')

# here I would like the fill legend to be *right* and the color legend left
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-12-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `order` option of `guide_legend`:

```
ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(cyl, hp, fill = as.character(gear))) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(cyl, disp, color = as.character(cyl))) +
  labs(fill = 'fill', color = 'color') +
  guides(fill  = guide_legend(order = 1),
         color = guide_legend(order = 2))
```

[image]

Comment: Danke, Martin! That's exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: Surprising how hard it was to find this trick!  I don't normally care about the order but when using second y-axis with legend at the bottom it greatly helps readability to have them match their axis.